# strange effect with string comparisation with ==

Tags: java, string, comparison

I know that we shouldn't compare Strings with == and its better to use equals.
For so far I learned this should all be false.
So why does the first method return true?

```
private String ab = "AB";
private String ab2 = "A" + "B";
private String a = "A";
private String b = "B";
private String ab3 = a + b;

public void test () {
    System.out.println("ab == ab2" + ab==ab2);
    System.out.println("ab == ab3" + ab==ab3);
    System.out.println("ab == a+b" + ab==(a+b));
}
```

Comment: "For so far I learned this should all be false." Nope. Due to string literal interning...

Comment: Thats why I put for so far, we are always learning ;) (and some seniors here didn't know it to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the concatenation of literal `String`s are compiled into a single `String`, which will also be interned in the String pool. This code:

```
private String ab2 = "A" + "B";
```

is compiled to

```
private String ab2 = "AB";
```

`ab` and `ab2` point to the same literal String `"AB"`, thus they're `==`s.

Still, you should not trust comparison of `String`s with `==`, you should **always** compare their equality using `equals` method.

Comment: Like I said in mine first sentence that we shouldn't compare with == but equals.

Comment: @chillworld yes but that line is posted for future readers that won't read all your question and will go directly to the code.

Comment: oke np ;) and thx for the explication.

Answer (score 0):

It is called String interning:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

To summarize, since strings are immutable in Java, JVM optimizes by creating only one object for two string literals that are equal. Therefore, comparison returns true.